# ListView declared in layout is null in onCreateView

Tags: android, dialog, nullpointerexception, fragment

I'm trying to create a DialogFragment with a ListView and some Buttons. I'm declaring all of them i the layout file and the buttons are working fine but the ListView is null when i  use fineViewByID().

Here's my xml:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/category_picker" 
    android:layout_gravity="center" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvCategorys"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" >

    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAddNew"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/cpf_btnAddNew" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnConfig"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/cpf_btnConfig" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the FragmentDialog:
package com.example.spendo.fragments;

```
    imports....


    public class CategoryPickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements OnItemClickListener{
    private CategoryGroup categoryGroup;
    private ListView lvCategorys;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> lvAdapter;

    private Button btnAddNew, btnConfig;


    public CategoryPickerFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for DialogFragment
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category_picker, container);
        getDialog().setTitle("Hello");

        categoryGroup = General.getActiveCategoryGroup(this.getActivity());
        System.out.println(categoryGroup);

        btnAddNew = (Button) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnAddNew);
        btnConfig = (Button) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnConfig);
        lvCategorys = (ListView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lvCategorys);
        if(lvCategorys == null){ //this returns "lvCategorys is null"
            System.out.println("lvCategorys is null");
        }else{
            System.out.println(lvCategorys + " is not null");
        }

        lvAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, categoryGroup.getNameArray());
        System.out.println(lvAdapter);
        ArrayList<String> nameArray = categoryGroup.getNameArray();
        lvAdapter.clear();
        for(int i = 0; i < nameArray.size(); i++){
            lvAdapter.add((String) nameArray.get(i));
        }
        lvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        lvCategorys.setAdapter(lvAdapter);



        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    }
```

Does anyone see my problem. (I'm quite new to android, altho i've done some java in the past).

//Sverker

Comment: you need to call view.findViewById

Comment: this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lvCategorys); Is not correct?

Comment: no, because you search your subviews from `view`, since it is not added to the activity yet (it will only be after you return it).

Comment: It worked! Thank you, sorry about the silly question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to replace

```
btnAddNew = (Button) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnAddNew);
btnConfig = (Button) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnConfig);
lvCategorys = (ListView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lvCategorys);
```

with

```
btnAddNew = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAddNew);
btnConfig = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnConfig);
lvCategorys = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvCategorys);
```

Comment: +1 for answering the question in the answers section, not the question comments above!